# Java annotation processing from within java code

Tags: compilation, annotations, java-8

This is further question related to my post -> [java8 tools.jar annotation processing with apt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28323350/java8-tools-jar-annotation-processing-with-apt)

I have done the following bits of code to replace the apt tool with the java compiler.

First I create an annotation processor with javax libraries as below:

```
public class MyAnnotationProcessor extends AbstractProcessor {

    @Override
    public boolean process(Set<? extends TypeElement> annotations,
            RoundEnvironment roundEnv) {
        System.out.println("annotation processing");
        return false;
    }  

}
```

And then in my main piece of code I replace the statement `int aptReturnCode = com.sun.tools.apt.Main.process(myAnnotationProcessorFactory...)` with the code below:

```
DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject> diagnostics = new DiagnosticCollector<JavaFileObject>();
StandardJavaFileManager fileManager = compiler.getStandardFileManager(diagnostics, null, null);
Iterable<? extends JavaFileObject> compilationUnits = fileManager.getJavaFileObjectsFromStrings(Arrays.asList("C:/Test/FileToCompile.java"));
JavaCompiler.CompilationTask task = compiler.getTask(null, fileManager, diagnostics, null,
        null, compilationUnits);

ArrayList<Processor> processors = new ArrayList<Processor>();

processors.add( new MyAnnotationProcessor() );

task.setProcessors( processors );


boolean success = task.call();
```

But the problem is that the above statement returns true but does not trigger the System.out.println("annotation processing") statement.

Can any one see some thing obviously worng here ?

Many Thanks

Comment: Maybe because your processor is not interested in any annotations. It’s class must be either, be annotated with [`@SupportedAnnotationTypes`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/SupportedAnnotationTypes.html) or override [`getSupportedAnnotationTypes()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/AbstractProcessor.html#getSupportedAnnotationTypes--)

Comment: Good one mate. So to process all annotations found in my compilable code, my Processor class looks like this:

Comment: Good one mate. So to process all annotations found in my compilable code, my Processor class overrides the method as follows and now atleast the process method is trigerred.
 @Override
 public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() {
  
  
  HashSet<String> supportedAnnotations = new HashSet<String>();
  supportedAnnotations.add("*");
  return supportedAnnotations;
 }

Comment: `@Override public Set<String> getSupportedAnnotationTypes() { return` [`Collections.singleton("*")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#singleton-T-)`; }` but adding `@SupportedAnnotationTypes("*")` to the class declaration would be even simpler…

Answer (score 0):

You should use javax.annotation.processing.Messager instead of println.

```
Messager msg = processingEnv.getMessager();
msg.printMessage(Diagnostic.Kind.NOTE, "test");
```

Diagnostic.kind contains several types of messages you print. ERROR type will stop compilation process.